# Checking whether a sub site exist in site collection using client object model

Tags: client-object-model

I want to check a sub site exist in site collection. I site exist a new one will be created.This is what I have tried:

```
                int siteLanguage = 1033;
                //Create a new webCreateInformation object to specify the properties of the new site being created.
                Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
                var newUrl = contextUrl + title;
                clientContext.Load(oWebsite);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //var subWeb = (from w in oWebsite.Webs where w.Url == webUrl select w).SingleOrDefault();
                var subWeb = (from w in oWebsite.Webs where w.Url == newUrl select w).SingleOrDefault();
                if(subWeb==null)
                {                
                WebCreationInformation webCreateInfo = new WebCreationInformation();
                webCreateInfo.Description = description;
                webCreateInfo.Language = siteLanguage;
                webCreateInfo.Title = title;
                webCreateInfo.Url = title;
                webCreateInfo.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = true;
                webCreateInfo.WebTemplate = templateId;

                //Adding a new site under the root web

                Web oNewWebsite = oWebsite.Webs.Add(webCreateInfo);

                // Retreiving the server properties to the client context. Here we are retreiving the web server url and the time it was created.

                clientContext.Load(oNewWebsite,
                    Website => Website.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    Website => Website.Created);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                ViewBag.Message = "Site created.";
            }
                else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "already exist";
            }
```

but it is not working, got an error like `collection not initialized`.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the following **modified** example for enumerating all sites within site collection:

```
function enumWebs(propertiesToRetrieve, success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   ctx.load(rootWeb,propertiesToRetrieve);
   result.push(rootWeb);
   var colPropertiesToRetrieve = String.format('Include({0})',propertiesToRetrieve.join(',')); 
   var enumWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
   {
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,colPropertiesToRetrieve);
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                enumWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };
   enumWebsInner(rootWeb,result,success,error);    
}
```

**Usage**

Print web sites title:

```
enumWebs(['Title'],
   function(webs){
       for(var i = 0; i < webs.length;i++){
          console.log(webs[i].get_title());                               
       }
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

**IMPORTANT**

After getting all subsites from sitecollection you need to pass one by one subsite to below mentioned function to check if it is already exist or not.

```
bool WebExists(string siteUrl, string webUrl)
{
    //connect to the root site
    using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
    {
        // load up the root web object but only 
        // specifying the sub webs property to avoid 
        // unneeded network traffic
        var web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web, w =&gt; w.Webs);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        // use a simple linq query to get any sub webs with the URL we want to check
        var subWeb = (from w in web.Webs where w.Url == webUrl select w).SingleOrDefault();
        if (subWeb != null)
        {
          // if found true
          return true;
        }
      }
      // default to false...
      return false;
}
```

**You would call this as follows:**

```
var siteExists = WebExists("http://host/sites/site/", "http://host/sites/site/subsite");
```

Comment: sorry.. i want like, if the site already exist then it should not create a new site. if the site doesn't exist then it should create a new site.                  var subWeb = (from w in oWebsite.Webs where w.Url == newUrl select w).SingleOrDefault();// i nedd this checking. 
                if(subWeb==null)
                {

Comment: Please check updated answer. It might helps you. Because you are passing the site collection URL & checking in the code with same URL that if it is exist or not.

Comment: Thank you.. the following part in your code helped  :)                                                          context.Load(web, w =>; w.Webs);      // forgot to include this step.                                                     var subWeb = (from w in web.Webs where w.Url == webUrl select w).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
 public bool SubSiteExists(string siteUrl, string subSiteTitle,ClientContext context)
        {
            var web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web, w => w.Webs);
            context.ExecuteQuery();   
            var subWeb = (from w in web.Webs where w.Title == subSiteTitle select w).SingleOrDefault();
            if (subWeb != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```